# A natural Poisson bivector on the tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry, exterior-algebra, poisson-geometry

For a smooth manifold $M$, there is a natural $1$-form $\theta$ on $T^*M$ such that $\Bbb d \theta$ is a symplectic form. Somewhat symetrically, on $TM$ there is [a natural tangent field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle#Canonical_vector_field_on_tangent_bundle) $V$. Is it possible, then, to act symetrically and construct some "exterior derivative" $\Bbb d$ such that $\Bbb d V$ should be a Poisson bivector?

I know that, if $P$ is a Poisson bivector, then such an exterior derivative exists, using the [Schouten-Nijenhuis braket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schouten%E2%80%93Nijenhuis_bracket), as $[P, \cdot]$ - but it is exactly the Poisson bivector that I am missing!

Comment: The musical isomorphism requires a riemannian metric. If you have a riemannian metric then you can directly pull back the symplectic form or the symplectic potential to $TM$. If you have no additional structure on your manifold, then no such structure exists on the tangent bundle.

Comment: @Uldreth: I didn't pay attention to what I was writing. I have removed that paragraph, thank you.